# Defining an array size with a variable in a structure

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have tried defining an array size with a variable in C++ before and although I do not fully understand the concept of dynamic memory, I made it work. However, I don't know how to do the same thing to the array 'point' in this case.

```
num=50;
struct pos
{
double x;
};

 struct pos point[num];
```

Is there anything obvious that I am overlooking?

Comment: Arrays cannot have dynamic size in standard C++.

Comment: *Is there anything obvious that I am overlooking?* `std::vector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types of array sizes have to be compile time constants, so the compiler knows how much memory to reserve.

```
int count = 50;
int arr[count] // error!

static const int count = 50;
int arr[count]; // OK!
```

The other option is dynamically allocated memory in which the size is known at run time.

```
int count = 50;
int* arr = new int[count];
delete [] arr;
```

However, generally you don't want to be dealing with raw pointers and memory allocation on your own, and should instead prefer:

```
#include <vector>

int count = 50;
std::vector<int> arr(count);
```

This will also work for any custom types you have provided they are copyable (hint: your example `pos` structure is copyable):

```
#include <vector>

int count = 50;
std::vector<pos> arr(count);

arr[0].x = 1;
// ... etc
arr[49].x = 49;
```

`std::vector` has a rich interface, and all the details [can be found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Comment: Another option, if don't want `vector`'s functionality, is to use `unique_ptr<int[]> arr( new int[count]; )`

Comment: Yes, I'm glad that `unique_ptr` addressed the nastiness that was `auto_ptr` not handling arrays properly.